# HTML5 and Mobile Website Development

Tags: iphone, ipad, html

HTML5 is said to be the future of web. My question is based on the features that HTML5 provides like Offline Access, Local Storage, Input Forms, etc , is the focus been almost entirely on Mobile Website Development ?
E.g. An Offline Caccess would practically make sense only for Mobile or Tablet devices and not really on desktops.
Similarly for many HTML5 form features..

Also which mobile browser has the highest support for HTML5 features ?

Please suggest.

Comment: I love it when a question gets closed just as I'm writing the final few words of a 5 paragraph answer. Nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

["Best"](http://mobilehtml5.org/) is subjective.

HTML5 form features such as `placeholder` are useful for every platform.

Answer (score 0):

> E.g. An Offline Caccess would practically make sense only for Mobile or Tablet devices and not really on desktops.

How about laptops? Offline Gmail or Google Docs seems like it could be handy on a long plane flight.